# iPad Pro simulator not working on Xcode 8.0

Tags: ipad, xcode8, simulator

I've tried running my Xcode 8.0 project with the iPad Pro simulator many times, but won't work.

This is the result I receive every time:

[image]

Comment: Change the window scale a few times.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, it works! Is this ridiculous? It wasted me one hour! Would you like to put an answer? I will put an answer to help someone else if you are not interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the window scale a few times.

1. Window>Scale>50%
2. Window>Scale>100%
3. Repeat

[image]